# Should both client and server have "--remote" arg in OpenVPN?

Tags: openvpn

I'm reading the Mastering OpenVPN book, and in the examples, the server doesn't use the "--remote" arg, but the client does. This makes sense - the server just listens for connections, while the client needs to know what IP/domain to connect to.

What happens if you set both the server and the client with the "--remote" flag? Then effectively, neither side is the server or the client, as both would have nearly identical configurations. Will both try to connect to each other? Will this cause problems? Does this also mean that without the "--remote" flag, a server can listen to connections from anyone, while setting the flag means it will only accept connections from that one specific host?

Edit: I'm talking about using OpenVPN with pre-shared keys here - not certificates. I haven't gotten to the point in the book where it explains certificates, so I don't know if this matters.